# How to column the page at the top and bottom with bootstrap col

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to design my page in such a way
I want to set `col2` and `col3` at the top and `col1` and `col4` at the bottom with different styles.

```js
import React from 'react'
import "./style.css"

const Footer = () => {

return(
    <div className="footer">
        <span className="col1">
            All&nbsp;rights&nbsp;reserved
        </span>
        <span className="col2">
            <span className='content21'>Join us</span> 
            <span className='content22'>Home</span> 
            <span className='content23'>Services</span> 
            <span className='content24'>Case study</span> 
        </span>
        <span className="col3">
            <span>Team</span>
            <span>Contact us</span>
            <span>sitemap</span>
        </span>
        <span className="col4">Connect with us</span>
    </div>

)
}

export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Footer container */
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Change to column layout */
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333; /* Change the background color to your preference */
  color: white; /* Change the text color to your preference */
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px; /* Adjust the height based on your design */
}

/* First column at the bottom */
.col1 {
  margin-top: auto; /* Push to the bottom */
}

/* Second column at the top */
.col2 {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: auto; /* Push to the top */
}

/* Individual items in the second column */
.col2 span {
  margin-right: 20px; /* Adjust the spacing between items */
}

/* Third column at the top */
.col3 {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: auto; /* Push to the top */
}

/* Individual items in the third column */
.col3 span {
  margin-right: 20px; /* Adjust the spacing between items */
}

/* Fourth column at the bottom */
.col4 {
  margin-top: auto; /* Push to the bottom */
}

/* Style individual items in the fourth column if needed */
```